# Pandas Dataframe SettingWithCopyWarning copy-method

Tags: python, pandas

I have this program for demonstration:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'foo':[100, 111, 222], 
     'bar':[333, 444, 555]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

list = [333,444]

dferg = df.loc[df.bar.isin(list)]

dferg['test'] = 123
```

I get the warning:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas- 
docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  dferg['test'] = 123
```

when i change:

```
dferg = df.loc[df.bar.isin(list)]
```

to

```
dferg = df.loc[df.bar.isin(list)].copy()
```

there is no more warning. But is this the best way?

Comment: Well looks like they are deprecating "*the best way*" which was setting `dferg.is_copy = False` so looks like copying again is the new best way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dferg = df.loc[df.bar.isin(list)]` is a get operation which can return either a view or  a copy. Calling `.copy()` is explicitly telling it's actually a copy, thus no warning is raised. `dferg['test'] = 123` modifies the original `df` too, so pandas warns you in case you might want to work with a copy instead of a view.

Think about whether you want the original DataFrame `df` to be modified by what ever assignments you do to `dferg`. If you actually want to modify the first DataFrame, put everything in a single `.loc` call:

```
df.loc[df.bar.isin(list), 'test'] = 123 # sets 123 in df
```

else, just explicitly call copy like you said:

```
dferg = df.loc[df.bar.isin(list)].copy()
dferg['test'] = 123 # ONLY modifies dferg, not original df
```